# Access: Compare two datetime values with query

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2013

Please help me to compare two datetime values with **WHERE clause** in access.

Problem is one datetime format is in **German e.g 12.03.2015 4:33:40 PM** 
while other is in **US format 12/3/2015 4:33:40 PM**.

**What i tried:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE (((Format([Edit Date],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM")) > #11/28/2016 12:31:30#));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "datetime format is this"? What data type is assigned to the Edit Date column? Because if its Date/Time, it will be sufficient just to do normal compare, `WHERE [Edit Date] > #other date#`

Comment: Datetime datatype is assigned to [EDIT DATE] column.

Comment: datetime stored in database is like this : 11.28.2016 12:31:30 . while  other datetime value is like this: 11/28/2016 12:31:30 .

Comment: The database does not store datetime in any sort of format. It's just Date/Time - displayed format varies according to locale, table properties etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `[Edit Date]` column is in Date/Time format, you just need normal comparison. Maybe the problem lies in the way you try to supply date in between #? Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE [Edit Date] > DateSerial(2016, 11, 28) + TimeSerial(12,31,30);
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE [Edit Date] > #2016-11-28 12:31:30#;
```

Comment: yep! i was doing it by wrong way Thanks for your help.